# Add "Visual Studio Web site" to "MVC 4 Web Project"

Tags: web, visual-studio-2012, webproject

Add "Visual Studio Web site" to "MVC 4 Web Project".

I have done following steps:
 - Created a new MVC 4 Web project using visual studio 2012.
 - Created a folder under this project.
 - Copied all the contents of website to this folder.
 - Include this folder in the project.
 - Build this project.

Getting errors "already contains definition for ..."

I think error is due to the different build model of web site and web project, in web project it is trying to build single assembly whereas in web site it creates separate assembly for every page. I am not sure how to fix this.

I can only think of one option to configure web prject in such a way it produces separate assembly for every page. I have tried the option "Do not merge, generate separate assembly for each page and control" but it doesn't fix the issue.

I am not sure how to configure web project in such a way it generates separate assembly per page / folder.

Comment: What files are giving errors?

Comment: cs files having partial classes